# FillTransition for JavaFX Label

Tags: java, javafx

Is there a way how I can make something like a FillTransition for a Label?

I basically just want to change the text color of the Label in an animated way.

Thank you already!

Comment: There is a [FillTransition](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javafx/animation/FillTransition.html) class, so… yes, there is a way.

Comment: I know there is one, but it needs a Shape and Label doesn't inherit from Shape. Maybe there is a way how to use FillTransition with a Label, but I don't know how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple solution would be using a `Text` node instead of a `Label`. `Text` extends `Shape` and therefore can be used with a `FillTransition`. On the other hand you loose the possibility of adding a background and the ellipsis functionality.

If you want to keep using a `Label`, I recommend animating the `textFill` property using a `Timeline`.

Example:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    Color fromColor = Color.BLACK;
    Color toColor = Color.ORANGE;

    Label label = new Label("hello world!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");

    Timeline timeline = new Timeline(
            new KeyFrame(Duration.ZERO, new KeyValue(label.textFillProperty(), fromColor)),
            new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(10), new KeyValue(label.textFillProperty(), toColor))
    );
    timeline.play();
    Scene scene = new Scene(new StackPane(label));
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

Comment: THANK YOU!
That was exactly what I was looking for!
I've already worked with Timelines but didn't know that they would also work with colors. :)

Comment: `KeyValue` works with numbers or anything implementing [`Interpolatable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/animation/Interpolatable.html) (which currently seems to be only `Color`).